# How can I get django-registration emails sent?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, postfix, django

I have a Django project on a Saucy EC2 instance, with a site's registration handled via django-registration, and after a few minutes and a few tries to register different email addresses, I am not seeing any emails from any attempts at registering users. (The only user that exists is the one created during the registration.) The settings.py file has:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

When I manually sent a test message through a port 25 telnet session, the manual email arrived fine. (I have Postfix installed.)

What should I be trying to do to enable emails to be sent by django-registration?

I tried setting EMAIL_HOST_USER to a valid email address and registered a new user again, but that didn't result in anything in my inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Django did not work out of the box with Postfix installed as the mailer; when I installed sendmail instead, my problem evaporated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look on the Postfix log file? I had something like this and the cause is Postfix do not accept the `From:` email address in the email generated by Django. After changing the `SERVER_EMAIL`, which default to `root@localhost` in settings.py to some sane value, then things work.